# Changing Image Source property when Button is clicked

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have added an image(image1) in my Xaml Editor, changed the source property to Source="/WpfApplication9;component/Images/a.png"

I have a button,
I want is, if I Clicked that button I want my image1 to change its source.
I have used this code but when i clicked the button the image1 that has the "a.png" became nothing, or  doesn't show something.

this is my code

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    image1.Source = (System.Windows.Media.ImageSource)this.Resources["/Resources/a.png"]; 
 }
```

this is my xaml

```
<Image Height="150" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="153,56,0,0" Name="image1" Stretch="Fill" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="200" Source="/WpfApplication9;component/Images/a.png" />
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably what you could try, using `BitmapImage` class to dynamically assign a new image source.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
 {
    image1.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Resources/a.png", UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
 }
```

Comment: Its just the same, I think it just clears the source property of my image

Comment: Its ok now thanks for your help